# CSS3 properties on ie8

Tags: html, css

I have a div and i gave it some css properties, it works on every other browser apart from 1e8 and below (as usuall). How can i make it work on ie8?
http://jsfiddle.net/WY5Cu/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WY5Cu/1/ You need content to make divs display.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks, man CSS3 won't work in IE8 anyways.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: I set the height ad width property :)

Comment: @Torsten Walter: I've tried using the webkit properties for everything nd it still doesn't work :(

Comment: By the way, on your fiddle link you’re using `-moz-box-shadow` and `-webkit-box-shadow`, neither of which have been needed since Firefox 3.6 / Chrome way-back-when. You could probably drop those. You can also forget about `-ms-` gradient declarations: IE10 will be the first browser to support these and it’s doing it unprefixed. http://caniuse.com/ has useful support tables that list whether the prefix is required or not for specific versions.

Comment: Oh thanks for the heads up, these older ie browsers don't support quite a lot of things so i just chuck them in and hope they work without reading their compatibility haha

Comment: For what it’s worth, I’ve found that because older browsers are a lot slower users generally prefer a clean and fast experience over one that’s loaded down with shadows and rounded corners and renders slowly. That’s why I stay away from the Javascript polyfill solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ – the gradient editor there will generate IE8 compatible background gradients.

For the `box-shadow`, this rule should emulate your current code somewhat:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=1, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
```

albeit without the inset shadow (I doubt there’s a way to do that in IE8).

To combine multiple filter declarations (for your shadow and gradient fill) you’ll need to chain them together with a space. For example:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=1, Direction=135, Color='#000000') progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 )";
```

For IE7 you’ll need to duplicate the IE8 rules, but with `filter` instead of `-ms-filter` and leave out the start and end quotes.

Comment: Oh thanks, so i'll just add a new css file to the page using <!--[if IE]>
right?

Comment: Nope, just chuck in your new `-ms-filter` and `filter` rules below your other styling. Other browsers don’t recognise them so just ignore it.

Comment: @SaffronHarris and colorzilla's gradient editor also allows you to generate the "cross browser css" from existing css gradient code or even an image. Definitely the best css gradient generator out there.

Comment: @Joonas - neat! I hadn’t realised that.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go through all the effort of enabling features in a browser that *doesn't natively support it* you can use [CSS3pie.](http://css3pie.com/)

This lets you use CSS3 features with IE browsers 6-8 (9 already supports *some* of them) with minimal effort. Just download, attach to your site and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) which makes IE 6 - 9 capable of supporting the properties you need (linear-gradient and box-shadow)